# Case statement not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query to display an alias column with respect to a column value.
below is my code

```
  CASE TRIM(channel_id)
  WHEN '' THEN 'General' 
  ELSE 'Specific'
END AS templateType
```

When the column channel id is empty/null the templateType column should show 'General'
else should show 'Specific'

I am getting wrong output 
Can anyone help me please..?

Comment: can you give sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CASE TRIM(IFNULL(channel_id,''))
     WHEN '' THEN 'General' 
     ELSE 'Specific'
END AS templateType
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN channel_id > '' THEN
  'Specific' 
ELSE
  'General'
END As templateType
```

**Aside:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN '' = '         ' THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END
```

Results:

```
same
```

Comment: @sandeep.mishra Just note that this method requires no extra functions i.e. `TRIM()` and `IFNULL()`